# Upgrading to Hibernate 4.1 and the "infamous" HibernateTemplate

Tags: java, spring, hibernate

I'm upgrading our project from Hibernate 3.0 to Hibernate 4.1.6. (And we are currently using spring 3.1)

I read in many articles and in HibernateTemplate documentation, that since version 4.0 HibernateTemplate is not supported and that I should replace it's usage with calling `sessionFactory.getCurrentSession()` to get a session.

Since this project was started with older version of Hibernate, where the use of `HibernateTemplate` was encouraged, we currently have 124 usages of `HibernateTemplate` across our project. I'm afraid that replacing all these occurrences with `sessionFactory.getCurrentSession()` might insert regression bugs in our project. In addition, there are some places where `HibernateTemplate` was used in a non-transactional context, where there is no 'current' session. What should I do in those cases? Open a new session and handle (close) it myself? That wasn't the case when I used `HibernateTemplate`.

Do you have some good strategy addressing these issues?

Thanks.

Relevant reading:

1. [Hibernate Vs. Spring - HibernateTemplate history](http://jroller.com/kimchy/entry/hibernate_vs_spring_hibernate_template)
2. [Hibernate Core Migration Guide](https://community.jboss.org/wiki/HibernateCoreMigrationGuide40)
3. [MIGRATING TO SPRING 3.1 AND HIBERNATE 4.1](http://blog.springsource.org/2012/04/06/migrating-to-spring-3-1-and-hibernate-4-1/)
4. [org.springframework.orm.hibernate3.HibernateTemplate](http://static.springsource.org/spring/docs/2.5.x/api/org/springframework/orm/hibernate3/HibernateTemplate.html)

Comment: Not contributing to answer still good read http://blog.springsource.com/2007/06/26/so-should-you-still-use-springs-hibernatetemplate-andor-jpatemplate/

Comment: also might be relevant: https://community.jboss.org/wiki/SessionsAndTransactions

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Okay, So this is what I actually did, I don't know if this is the best solution for this problem, but under our circumstances, and since I was looking for the most localized solution, it seemed best to me.

I have extended the springframework.orm.hibernate3.HibernateTemplate and created a new MyHibernateTemplate. The new template's main role is to override the doExecute method that most of the hibernate3.HibernateTemplate eventually lead to, and also supply some of the functionality that was provided by the old SessionFactoryUtils (like isSessionTransactional and applyTransactionTimeout).

The new doExecute replicates the logic of the old one, but instead of SessionFactoryUtils.getNewSession to get a session it first try to look for an open session getSessionFactory().getCurrentSession() :

```
boolean newSessionOpened = false;
Session session;

if (enforceNewSession){
    session = SessionFactoryUtils.openSession(getSessionFactory());
    newSessionOpened = true;
} else {
    try {
        // look for an open session
        session = getSessionFactory().getCurrentSession();
    }
    catch (HibernateException ex) {
        try {
            // if there isn't an open session, open one yourself
            session = getSessionFactory().openSession();
            newSessionOpened = true;
        } catch (HibernateException e) {
            throw new DataAccessResourceFailureException("Could not open Hibernate Session", ex);
        }
    }
}

// is the open session, is a session in a current transaction?
boolean existingTransaction = (!enforceNewSession &&
        (!isAllowCreate() || isSessionTransactional(session, getSessionFactory())));
```

You just need to close this session manually:

```
    finally {
    // if session was used in an existing transaction restore old settings
    if (existingTransaction) {
        //logger.debug("Not closing pre-bound Hibernate Session after HibernateTemplate");
        disableFilters(session);
        if (previousFlushMode != null) {
            session.setFlushMode(previousFlushMode);
        }
    }
    // if not and a new session was opened close it
    else {
        // Never use deferred close for an explicitly new Session.
        if (newSessionOpened) {
            SessionFactoryUtils.closeSession(session);
            //_log.info("Closing opened Hibernate session");
        }
    }
```

I'm Trying keep this answer short, but if there are any questions I can elaborate further about this problem.

Comment: This is a tough problem because of the amount of functionality in HibernateTemplate and friends. Before finding this post, I had already gone down approximately the same road as you describe, but cloned HibernateTemplate instead of extending it. I'm not sure that was the best strategy. I'm left with LOTS of functionality to account for, so I'm concerned about the stability of the resulting code. I know this is ancient history for you by now, but can you share more about your strategy, and how it panned out for you?

Answer (score 3):

Check out [this section](http://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/orm/4.1/manual/en-US/html_single/#architecture-current-session) in the docs. It says that `SessionFactory.getCurrentSession()` is pluggable and there is a [`ThreadLocalSessionContext`](http://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/core/3.5/api/org/hibernate/context/ThreadLocalSessionContext.html) implementation that keeps the 'current session' in the `ThreadLocal` rather than a JTA transaction. ThreadLocalSessionContext will also close the Session at the end of the hibernate Transaction created from that Session, so you don't have to worry about closing the `Session` yourself.

With regards to introducing regression bugs, upgrading a library will always have it's risks, especially so when it is something as core to your application as hibernate. The only advice I can give is to ensure your test suite has decent coverage before the upgrade. After all, that's the job of your test suite - to catch regression bugs.

Answer (score 0):

You can also continue to use `HibernateTemplate` with `getCurrentSession()`, as in many cases `openSession()` might not be the best choice as you will need to close sessions on your own.
To use currentSession you can add the following to manage transactions:

`<prop key="hibernate.transaction.jta.platform">org.hibernate.engine.transaction.jta.platform.internal.JBossAppServerJtaPlatform</prop>`

where the key's value will depend on your AS.